# Can you not assign a variable to a fnmatch function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I have the following code, it prints out the file but it doesn't assign it to the variable file so that i can open it

```
for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\####\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Data\\'):
    if  fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.csv'):
        scanReport = open(file)
        scanReader = csv.reader(scanReport)
```

Comment: What isn't being assigned? `scanReport` and `scanReader` are being constantly reassigned and overwritten every iteration where the condition holds.

Comment: i want the csv file i have in the folder to be assigned to file variable

Comment: `scanReport = open(file)` won't work you have to provide full path.

Comment: so i can't have it search for anything .csv related and if it matched then assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

`fnmatch` doesn't (and cannot) expand `file` into the proper path. It's just a wildcard pattern test.

`os.listdir` returns the file *names* not the file *paths*. match the filename (as you already do) but provide full path to `open` using `os.path.join` with your source directory:

```
the_dir = r'C:\Users\####\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Data'
for file in os.listdir(the_dir):
    if  fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.csv'):
        scanReport = open(os.path.join(the_dir,file))
```

or maybe it's better to use `glob.glob` in that case to get filter & absolute path at the same time.

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\####\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Data\*.csv'):
    scanReport = open(file)
```

Comment: which solution and what's the exact problem?

Comment: that worked! Thanks! I saw glob last night but wasn't able to try it out until now, thanks!